# elastic4s: extracting information from RequestSuccess[DeleteByQueryResponse]

Tags: scala, elastic4s

I have following code:

```
def delete(id: String) = {
    client.execute {
      deleteByQuery("myIndex", termQuery("id", id))
    }.await
  }

delete(id) match {
                case failure: RequestFailure => complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, failure.body.getOrElse("Unknown reason"))
                case success: RequestSuccess[DeleteByQueryResponse] => {
                  complete("I want to put info extracted from results here...")
                }
```

I observe that inside success object there is a field by name 'result', and it is of type Left[DeleteByQueryResponse].

RequestSuccess has a map method

```
final def map[V](f: U => V): Response[V] = RequestSuccess(status, body, headers, f(result))
```

where U is of same type as 'result'.

I am not really sure how to extract all relevant information from 'result'?

Comment: Not sure to understand the issue. Using `success.result` in the success case is not enough?

Comment: Invoking success.result takes control to definition of ErrorFuture...no idea why this behaviour.

Comment: Still don't understand? What's `ErrorFuture`? Can you share the error?